# Switch between Wordpress websites easy for an end user

Tags: customization, login

On of our clients has several Wordpress websites (not a multisite). Is there a way/plugin that can make it easy for them to switch between these sites without having to login all the time?

They should only have editor rights (so not being able to update plugins etc.)

I can't find a simple solution for this, but maybe I haven't looked in the right place.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Are they on separate domains, or the same domain? Login/logout to one site shouldn't affect another if they're on different domains?

Comment: If it's just a question of convenience, maybe 'SSO' is a helpful search term. I found this which may be helpful if you want them to e.g. manage logins in one place and signing in to one place signs you in to many Wordpresses at once https://wordpress.org/support/topic/sso-on-many-wp-websites/

Comment: Migrating to multisite would be the easiest, otherwise you're asking the generic case of how to implement federated login/single sign on/SSO. This won't be a trivial task, particularly as you already have user databases set up on the sites already that would require a migration

Comment: Hi Tom, thank you for your answer. I will look into multisite as well, seems indeed a tedious task, but might be worth the try.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly what you're looking for is 'single sign on' or SSO.

There's a plugin called WP Auth Server which provides SSO between Wordpress websites without the need for any extra sign-on service. Maybe it'll do what you want. I don't have first hand experience with this or SSO in Wordpress but have set it up in other contexts.

> Connect your app to WordPress or use SSO to connect multiple websites
> with the same username and passwords. No 3rd party servers are needed
> with WP OAuth Server. Everything you need is in this plugin.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/oauth2-provider/

Comment: Sorry I could have made this clearer, they are on separate domains.

I know that for example ManageWP can do this, but that's tool is totally not suitable for an end user who just wants to switch easily between different Wordpress websites and should not have access to plugins etc.    I'll have a look at the SSO option, thanks!

Comment: Not sure if it would help you, but perhaps changing the cookie timeout would help this issue too, then admin users would only have to login once and they'd stay logged in (to each site, individually)